# open mail in backuped profile from old thunderbird version thunderbird 68.12

Tags: backup, thunderbird

I'm working with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

I'm regularly saving my thunderbird profile folder including all the mails.

In the meanwhile I upgraded to Thunderbird 91.7.

Now I need a mail backupt in my old profile from thunderbird 68.12.

Thunderbird 91.7 is not able to open a profile made by thunderbird 68.12.

But a thunderbird 68 installation over terminal seems not possible anymore:

```
sudo apt install thunderbird=68.12.0

> E: Version '68.12.0' for 'thunderbird' was not found
```

Nor do I find a downloadable installation file on thunderbird.net or mozilla.org. I just find releasenotes without installation files.
https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/68.12.1/releasenotes/

How may I open my mails in my backupt old profile?

Comment: @guiverc I just added "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

Comment: How did you backup your Thunderbird mail? You'll end up coping files/folders into ~/.thunderbird, and then starting Thunderbird with `thunderbird -P`, and creating a new profile for the old files. Or, copying specific mail folders into your current profile. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.thunderbird`.

Comment: @heynnema I'm doing the backup by saving the profile-folder. 

But Thunderbird 91.7 is not able to open a profile made by thunderbird 68.12.

Comment: How do you know TB 91.7 won't open the older profile folder? What did you try?